# Random terraform dial tcp: lookup no such host errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I run terraform apply, I get random "terraform dial tcp: lookup no such host errors". Sometimes they go away when I run apply again. Here are a some examples:

`Post "https://iam.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup iam.amazonaws.com on [2001:8a0:6f38:7c00::1]:53: no such host
Post "https://firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com on [2001:8a0:6f38:7c00::1]:53: no such host
Post "https://events.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup events.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com on [2001:8a0:6f38:7c00::1]:53: no such host`

I can't find any problem with my network and definitely not a problem looking up names.
I sometimes also get this with terraform destroy

Comment: Are you using custom service endpoints in your provider configuration?

Comment: No. All default stuff.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having same issues with eu-west-1 endpoints to the point I had to pin them in my `/etc/hosts` just to complete a plan. Using aws provider version `5.9.0` with terraform `1.5.0`

Comment: I did not unfortunately. Never got to understand what was happening. Never got this problem in any other project

Comment: I managed to fix my issue but I'm unclear exactly how that resolved this issue. It was using a VPN with it's own DNS settings. There was a know  issue TF not picking DNS setting from a VPN but this was fixed a while back. I switched DNS settings on the VPN and it started working. I'm still trying to understand why that's the case.